# Frames and Statics Question

Tags: mechanical-engineering, statics, mechanical

[image]
this is an image describing an exam question I have to practice on, and I am so stuck.

Comment: Start with the assumption that sum of force vectors must be zero, since it's not accelerating.  Then convert everything you see there into force vectors. Assume sum of moments about any point must be zero because nothing is accelerating in spinning about those points.  Pick points that apply lever arms of 0 to each unknown to generate some more equations.

Comment: For questions which are, (or look like) homework, please [edit] the question to include the steps that you have already attempted and make it clear where you are stuck.

Comment: For the system, you can write three equilibrium equations and two additional conditions (at internal hinges B & C), thus you have more equations than the unknowns (4). The system is "unstable".